# Exchange Full Access issue

Tags: permissions, exchange-2010, email-server, users

I was just hired as a System Admin for a small company. They use Exchange 2010 for their Mail Server. I've never had a permission issue like this with Exchange because I worked for a larger firm with less responsibility before. Their old system admin is LONG GONE, so I can't ask him what he did.

The issue: Right now ANYONE can gain access to a mailbox and view the mail in the mailbox. This is disabled by default you say and you have to grant them full access ? You are right, but the old System Admin I guess didn't know what he was doing. **SO right now user A can open up user B mailbox with out being granted permission.**

So here is what I found out. Every user in EMC Full Access Permission has Exchange Server group granted. Within the Exchange Server Group, Domain User's is a Member Of. Within Domain User's all user's are listed as Members. So my guess is because of this all users can access ANY mailbox? Well GOOD News. The company is small (35 people) and they are not computer savvy, so hopefully no one has figured out they can open anyone's mailbox.(From what I can tell no).

Next thing I did was with my domain user in EMC, delete Exchange Servers Group in FUll Access Permissions and grant access to my user. I made sure that my memeber was apart of the Exchange Server Group. Went to our OWA site and now I don't have permission to my own mailbox. Re did everything to the way it was with my user and now I'm stuck.

Any help? I would think granting a single user that is in the Exchange Server group, Full Access to that mailbox would enable them to open that mailbox???? I guess I am wrong.

Comment: Three letters ... WTF?  Why are users in the Exchange Servers group?

Comment: Again I don't know?!? I didn't configure this system. I mean I understand role's and AD but I don't understand what the old system admin did to cause this. Anyways your comment is not helpful.

Comment: There are not users in the Exchange Server Group, just Domain Group.